# php sort filenames with an underscore

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of filenames that I aquire using DirectoryIterator. I am trying to get the filenames to sort so they would be in order like so, this is the way they appear on the server.

```
    2DAYSALEGATE_PG1.jpg
    2DAYSALEGATE_PG2.jpg
    722_PG1.jpg
    PW_PG2_COKE_A.jpg
    PW_PG3_COKE_A.jpg
    PWBY4_DELI-1.jpg
```

When aquiring the file names they are coming out like this. I have tried to use a sort, natsort and natcasesort. The filename the underscore character is considered after the letters. What can I do to get the underscore to sorted as a priority character.

```
array(6) {
[0]=>
 string(20) "2DAYSALEGATE_PG1.jpg"
[1]=>
 string(20) "2DAYSALEGATE_PG2.jpg"
[2]=>
 string(11) "722_PG1.jpg"
[5]=>
 string(16) "PWBY4_DELI-1.jpg"
[3]=>
 string(17) "PW_PG2_COKE_A.jpg"
[4]=>
 string(17) "PW_PG3_COKE_A.jpg"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the sort_flags parameter when you used sort?

Comment: yes I tried everything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the php `usort` method, check it out [here](https://www.php.net/usort)
with `usort` you can implement your custom `compare to` function and sort the array according to it.

the custom `compare to` function is `int callback ( mixed $a, mixed $b )` , you should return a value less than 0 if `$a < $b` , zero if equal and a value bigger than 0 when `$a > $b`

implement your preferred order of sorting using this method

example:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  $aTemp = str_replace('_', '0', $a);
  $bTemp = str_replace('_', '0', $b);     
  return strcmp($aTemp,$bTemp);
}

 usort($arr, "cmp");
```

Comment: So this is what I came up with  

    function cmp($a, $b) {  
 
    $aTemp = str_replace('_', 0, $a);  
 $bTemp = str_replace('_', 0, $b);  

 if ($aTemp == $bTemp) {  
  return 0;  
 }  
   
 return ($aTemp < $bTemp) ? -1 : 1;  
    }  

    usort($arr, "cmp");

Comment: Sorry I cannot figure out how to get this code to format correctly to display here.

Comment: no no, instead of == and <, just use 'return strcmp($aTemp,$bTemp)', its the natural string compare function

Comment: This answer is provably incorrect. https://3v4l.org/vF1jb  It doesn't provide the required result.

Comment: @mickmackusa u realize almost 10 years passed right?

Comment: Why mention time? It is irrelevant to correctness.  While I help improve Stack Overflow content, I review all posts for correctness, regardless of age.  Researchers do not care about age, they care about what works and they hate it when an answer's score misleads them about answer quality.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you can do here. Lexically, the underscore has a higher ASCII value than any alphanumeric character.

Replacing the underscore with a low ASCII value like \x01, then sorting, then replacing the low ASCII value with an underscore, will give the result you want, but that seems pretty expensive for a trivial change in order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the fact that the underscore appears in the ascii table in a small section of symbols between uppercase letters and lowercase letters is problematic for your desired natural sort.

To move that DELI string higher in the results, temporarily replace the underscores in every string with a space and use natural sorting.  The trouble with using 0 as a replacement character is that when the new zero follows another integer, it is effectively multiplying that integer by 10 -- this creates an unreliable sort.

For best efficiency, call `str_replace()` inside of `array_multisort()`.  This will have a lower time complexity than calling `usort()`.  (`usort()` will need to call `str_replace()` twice for at least every element in the array, plus as many times as needed to break ties.)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jDjdN))

```
array_multisort(
    str_replace('_', ' ', $array),
    SORT_NATURAL,
    $array
);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => '2DAYSALEGATE_PG1.jpg',
    1 => '2DAYSALEGATE_PG2.jpg',
    2 => '722_PG1.jpg',
    3 => 'PWBY4_DELI-1.jpg',
    4 => 'PW_PG2_COKE_A.jpg',
    5 => 'PW_PG3_COKE_A.jpg',
)
```