# Display files from a specific folder in same order

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to display files from a filesystem in a html format in the **same order**.

I got a file name like this and it looks like this in the folder structure:

```
ABC_100_name.pdf
ABC_101_name.pdf
ABC_102_name.pdf
ABC_102A1_name.pdf
ABC_103_name.pdf
ABC_103A1_name.pdf
ABC_104_name.pdf
```

I am using `scandir()` without any sort parameters.
The result I get is:

```
ABC_100_name.pdf
ABC_101_name.pdf
ABC_102A1_name.pdf
ABC_102_name.pdf
ABC_103A1_name.pdf
ABC_103_name.pdf
ABC_104_name.pdf
```

Neither `sort()` nor other `sort-functions` seem to help me with this.
What am I getting wrong?

---

The array I get from `scandir()` is:

```
array(5) { 
[0]=> string(1) "." 
[1]=> string(2) ".." 
[2]=> string(16) "ABC_100_name.pdf" 
[3]=> string(18) "ABC_101A1_name.pdf" 
[4]=> string(16) "ABC_101_name.pdf" }
```

Comment: So what is the outcome of sorting the array?  It appears in this case PHP is putting A ahead of underscore and LS is putting A after underscore, but it's hard to tell if that's the case without more detail of what you've tried in the question.

Comment: Yep, that's what happening.
All sort functions I used are putting A before underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to move away from [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and use [readdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) you might be able to use the example #2:

```php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "$entry<br>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Note that the distinction here is given within the respective description:

> **scandir()**: Returns an array of files and directories from the directory.
>
> **readdir()**: Returns the name of the next entry in the directory. *The entries are returned in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem.*

Comment: Cheers, not the answer I wanted to get but after a little more research it seems to be the only useful possibility.

Comment: @zool - yeah, i very much understand. I use `glob()` a fair bit and it too does not handle looping via sort *(AFAIK)* and always have to fall back to using this method. The lack of including the full file path is kind of a PITA, eh. Anyway, thanks for the upvote. Glad it worked out for ya.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
$customSort = function($s1, $s2) {
    $length = min(strlen($s1), strlen($s2));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        if ($s1[$i] === $s2[$i]) continue;
        if ($s1[$i] === '_') return -1;
        return strcmp($s1[$i], $s2[$i]);
    }
    return 0;
};

usort($filenames, $customSort);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I - again - adjusted a little and I am using something similar to this from here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416765/php-sort-filenames-with-an-underscore)
for my specific case :)

It's much easier than you tink most of the time :D